# Enabling NNE for go oracle drivers (ora, goracle)

Tags: oracle, go, nne, goracle

I have a `go` service which communicates with an Oracle database. Now, I need to encrypt that traffic using Oracle NNE (Native Network Encryption). For that, I need to set `sql.net.encryption_client` parameter on the client to `required`, as our Oracle server doesn't force encryption (for legacy reasons).

We are using `goracle` driver and I don't see any ways of setting that parameter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[Per driver developers], there is no way of programmatically setting that parameter at this time; however there is a workaround (that I've just tested and confirmed working) - create sqlnet.ora file with one line `sql.net.encryption_client=required` and add an environment variable `TNS_ADMIN=<folder path to sqlnet.ora file>`.

This will have the driver to require native network encryption on the client.

Comment: A missing link for ["Per the driver maintainers"](https://github.com/go-goracle/goracle/issues/138).

Comment: @kostix added the link

Comment: The 'driver maintainers' referred to are actually Oracle employees, and are not the maintainer of the goracle driver.

Comment: I changed "maintainers" to "developers" in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle network encryption options and other network options are controlled by Oracle Net configuration, not by the scripting language drivers.

- For users of Oracle Instant Client a solution is to put your sqlnet.ora (containing the `SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT = required` directive and related options) in a `network/admin` subdirectory, as mentioned in the Instant Client installation instructions (Linux [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html#ic_x64_inst), Windows [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html#ic_winx64_inst)).  This directory is pre-created on Linux with Instant Client 18.3 onwards.
- Alternatively set the environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` to a directory, and put your `sqlnet.ora` file in that directory.

Comment: Some drivers allow setting those directly thru the driver (e.g. ODP.NET) and that's what I was looking for in goracle driver originally. As per your response on GitHub I've understood that goracle driver doesn't supply that capability and I needed to create sqlnet.ora and set TNS_ADMIN.